# Configuring a map on powerBI having a multi-layer hierarchal locations (country, governorate, district) while also being filtered by program

Tags: dictionary, powerbi-desktop

I have a list of programs, each program supports services in a certain area in Lebanon, i want them disaggregated by governorate and district levels. i want to filter them by a slicer by program name.
i.e., when i choose program x, i want the map to show Lebanon, highlighting the distribution of services in a certain district. i am struggling with how to structure my data.

i created a table which has the following attributes as shown in picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LkY2.png)

the rows are the number of services per program, it still didnt work

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode